# Cannot remove object for key in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

For some weird reason I cannot delete some of the keys in my NSUserDefaults.  I am doing:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "currentSelectedCategoryID")
print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "currentSelectedCategoryID"))
```

When I print the value, it shows the exact same value `"58707"` before the object was removed.  I've even tried `UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "currentSelectedCategoryID")` and it's doing the same thing.

Why can't I delete my key?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I was sharing my user defaults with my share extension, and I didn't remove the key for that user default object.

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "currentSelectedCategoryID")
if let shared = UserDefaults(suiteName: {YOUR SUITE NAME}) {
     shared.removeObject(forKey: currentSelectedCategoryID)
}
```